# How to beat helicopter in chemical plant?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

can anyone suggest a method to bear the arkham knight helicopter in the chemical plant? I have died several times and can't seem to kill it.

Comment: Keep moving.  When he shoots a missile at you, use your strafe-jets to quickly move out of the way.  I don't remember there being much else to it.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft please don't answer questions in comments [-how many points does this guy have anyways- -20653- -...k-]

Comment: @blueraja your comment as an answer that's It!!

Comment: @ardaozkal: It's been a while since I played, so my memory is fuzzy - I wasn't sure if there was more to it, and I didn't want to provide an incorrect answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep strafing.  When he shoots a missile at you, use your strafe-jets to quickly move out of the way.  And keep shooting him, of course.